# Is there a method to cause kernel panic in userland?

Tags: linux, kernel

I'm trying to make kernel panic in usermode.

But I can't kernel module and sysrq-trigger.
It restricted.

Can I trigger kernel panic?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you find a bug, no.

If you want a panic, create a new syscall and compile+install the new kernel.
The syscall should just simply call panic().

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
sudo killall -6 init
```

If you run this multiple times, then it should panic. (Does not work on all Linux distributions)

Comment: It would be great if you can provide some explanation with your code. Then, more people will receive benefit, I suppose.